# Toggle a select element on span hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It appears my first attempt at asking this question was rather vague so, I'll reformat my question.

I'm currently working with the `<select></select>` element and I have stripped the element of all it's styling in an attempt to apply my own. I have managed to style the element in a manner that is more visually appealing. However, that being said I'm having difficulty when I try to interact with the element.

I can't seem to open the element when the span is positioned directly over the element; however If I use `pointer-events:none;` the span then looses it's hover.

I may be missing the point entirely and it may be a simple fix, but any help is much appreciated.

I have structured my element as follows,

```css
/* CSS */

#s-wrap {
  background-color: #0ff;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
input,
select,
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
}
input + span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
input:hover + span {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.frm-ele {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin: .5em .5em;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  border: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.sel-ele {
  width: 130px;
}
#arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #4f4f4f;
  border-right: 3px solid #4f4f4f;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 146px;
}
#wrap span:hover > #arrow {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#wrap span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  padding: .78em 0;
  margin: .5em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="s-wrap">
  <div id="wrap">
    <select name="day" required="" class="frm-ele sel-ele">
      <option value="">Day</option>
      <?php for ($day=1 ; $day <=3 1; $day++) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo strlen($day)==1 ? '0'.$day : $day; ?>">
        <?php echo strlen($day)==1 ? '0'.$day : $day; ?>
      </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select><span class="arr"><div id="arrow"></div></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*The element in the page looks a like this;*[image]

I saw this code in another post here on Stack, but it is not suported in firefox, so this solution is no good for me unless I can jimmy it to work in firefox. However, I'm not skilled enough with Jquery to do that.

I have included this code below;

**Sourced Code**

```
$('span').click(function() {
  var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
  $('select')[0].dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

UPDATED: Re-structured my question, and supplied all elements.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I have taken some time to review my question please look it over, if there is anything else you need let me know; I'll do my best to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sibling selector `~` with `pointer-event: none;` on `<span>` element:

```css
/* CSS */

#s-wrap {
  background-color: #0ff;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
input,
select,
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
}
input + span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
input:hover + span {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.frm-ele {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin: .5em .5em;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  border: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.sel-ele {
  width: 130px;
}
#arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #4f4f4f;
  border-right: 3px solid #4f4f4f;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 146px;
}
#wrap select {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#wrap select:hover ~ span > #arrow {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#wrap span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  padding: .78em 0;
  margin: .5em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="s-wrap">
  <div id="wrap">
    <select name="day" required="" class="frm-ele sel-ele">
      <option value="day">Day</option>
      <option value="day-2">Day 2</option>
    </select><span class="arr"><div id="arrow"></div></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have taken some time to review my question please look it over, if there is anything else you need let me know; I'll do my best to provide.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't beleive it was that simple. Many thanks for your assistance!